# USING windows control library in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a control library by adding refrence to office interop excel to do some excel automation in client.The control works fine in windows forms Now i need to add the control in asp.net can somebody tell how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to the library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steps for embedding a windows forms user control in web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270079/steps-for-embedding-a-windows-forms-user-control-in-web-page)

Answer (score 3):

a windows class library will work just fine in asp.net.  however, if you make a windows from control (or user control, etc) the control (etc.) will NOT work in asp.net.

all you have to do is add a reference to the assembly in your project. If your assembly references other assemblies, you will probably have to reference those in your project as well.  As long as you do not attempt to create instances of controls that have a informs UI, you should be OK.

Comment: Yes i have windows control library but that library refers office interop wheth i have to copy office interop also in  root directory with control library dll.because my control is not displaying in asp.net page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Office Interop in an ASP.NET application, or any other server-based application. Please see [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757), and please don't try it.