# Using windows control in web form

Tags: c#

We have made a simple windows control which we want to use in web form.But we are not able to do it. we just found this solution in internet but this solution is not giving any output

Code for windows control

```
<pre lang="cs">namespace WinformUsrCntl
 {
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
public UserControl1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
public void setText(string text)
{
  label1.Text = text;
}
}
}</pre>
```

Implementation in webform :-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Defualt</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function SendMessageToWinControl() {
 var winCtrl = document.getElementById("myName");
 winCtrl.innerHTMl("Message sent from the HTML page!!");
 }       
</script>
<style type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
 <h1>
    Windows Form Control:</h1>
   <input type="button" onclick="SendMessageToWinControl()" value="Send Message" />
       <br/>
    <object id="myName" width="100px"               classid="http:WinformUsrCntl.dll#WinformUsrCntl.UserControl1"
       VIEWASTEXT />
</div>
</form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270079/steps-for-embedding-a-windows-forms-user-control-in-web-page) you might find something

Answer (score 0):

Would it not make more sense to create a custom web server control, and wrap the windows control within it?  You could then expose all the properties and behaviour you wish, and use it as normal on ASP.NET.

More info on custom controls here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy(v=vs.100).aspx